# Why is Excel Pivot's 'Running total' option so much faster than Access DSUM?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, cumulative-sum

I am wondering, if I make a pivottable in Excel from a recordset with about 50000 lines, it takes about 30 seconds to produce a running total in a date field. Yet when I want to achieve the same result in an Access table, the DSUM takes over 30 minutes. Same data... Why is there so much performance difference? What does Excel do in the background?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article helpful:
http://azlihassan.com/apps/articles/microsoft-access/queries/running-sum-total-count-average-in-a-query-using-a-correlated-subquery

Here's what it says about Dsum, DLookup, etc.

> They  involve VBA calls, Expression Service calls, and they waste
> resources (opening additional connections to the data file.)
> Particularly if JET must perform the operation on each row of a query,
> this really bogs things down.

Alternatives include looping through the recordset in VBA or creating a subquery. If you need to use DSUM, make sure your field is indexed and avoid text fields.